# how to assign a hotkey for orientation "local", instead of a orientation menu

Tags: modeling

how to assign a hotkey for orientation, when I press one time hotkey, directly change to "local", instead of a menu, I don't want to choose orientation in a menu everytime, it so much waste time, in 3Dmax I can easily change each orientation by each hotkey, every time just one press, how can I do it in blender?

[image: orientation]

[image]

Comment: : (   anyone can help me???

Comment: so poor blender, even a basic hotkey not exist, maybe i should go back to 3dmax